# Spartacus Angular Search Box Suggestions not working for iPad device

Tags: spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

I am facing a weird issue only on the actual iPad device. I am using the below code to get the suggestions list but I am receiving an EMPTY list of suggestions for iPad. Though it is working for all other devices and browsers. But in iPad Safari and Chrome it's not working. Can you guys please help me out here?

Comment: any update one the same please? its super urgent !

Comment: Hi Team, do we have any answer for this issue ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack for response here! This is mysterious actually. Can you mayble double check if this is a CSS issue or a JS issue? Let me know if you need help how to figure that out.